# Can I get the absolute path to the current script in KornShell?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, path, ksh

Is it possible to find out the full path to the script that is currently executing in KornShell (ksh)?

i.e. if my script is in `/opt/scripts/myscript.ksh`, can I programmatically inside that script discover `/opt/scripts/myscript.ksh` ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could use:

```
## __SCRIPTNAME - name of the script without the path
##
typeset -r __SCRIPTNAME="${0##*/}"

## __SCRIPTDIR - path of the script (as entered by the user!)
##
__SCRIPTDIR="${0%/*}"

## __REAL_SCRIPTDIR - path of the script (real path, maybe a link)
##
__REAL_SCRIPTDIR=$( cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "$(command -v -- "$0")")" && pwd -P )
```

Comment: Great answer - I was hoping this would also work if you source the script i.e. '. /some/script.sh' but it doesn't.

Comment: @synthesizerpatel: In ksh93, you have `${.sh.file}` which also works for sourced files.

Comment: As pointed out by Gruik, this doesn't work if there is a symbolic link to the shell script itself. So if you link the command into, say, /usr/bin, then __REAL_SCRIPTDIR will return /usr/bin, which is (most likely) not what you want. You do apparently need readlink for this

Answer (score 10):

In korn shell, all of these $0 solutions fail if you are sourcing in the script in question. The correct way to get what you want is to use $_

```
$ cat bar

echo dollar under is $_
echo dollar zero is $0

$ ./bar

dollar under is ./bar
dollar zero is ./bar

$ . ./bar
dollar under is bar
dollar zero is -ksh
```

Notice the last line there? Use $_. At least in Korn. YMMV in bash, csh, et al..

Comment: This answer should be incorporated into the accepted one. I was struggling for half an hour sourcing my ksh script until I realized that I need `$_`.

Answer (score 9):

Well it took me a while but this one is so simple it screams.

```
_SCRIPTDIR=$(cd $(dirname $0);echo $PWD)
```

since the CD operates in the spawned shell with $() it doesn't affect the current script.

Answer (score 8):

How the script was called is stored in the variable $0. You can use `readlink` to get the absolute file name:

```
readlink -f "$0"
```

Comment: thanks for the $0 tip, what's readlink? doesn't seem to be on my system

Comment: Hmmm need something totally within ksh, no dependencies. Thanks though

Comment: I'm afraid that won't be possible - unless ksh has a possibility I am not aware of for interacting with the file system. What's your OS?

Comment: `$0` refers to the name of the command as it was invoked, and does not need to refer to a file system object.

Answer (score 4):

The variable $RPATH contains the relative path to the real file or the real path for a real file.

```
CURPATH=$( cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "$(command -v -- "$0")")" && pwd -P )

CURLOC=$CURPATH/`basename $0`

if [ `ls -dl $CURLOC |grep -c "^l" 2>/dev/null` -ne 0 ];then

    ROFFSET=`ls -ld $CURLOC|cut -d ">" -f2 2>/dev/null`

    RPATH=`ls -ld $CURLOC/$ROFFSET 2>/dev/null`

else

    RPATH=$CURLOC

fi

echo $RPATH
```

Comment: This does appear to be the only method available that copes with the situation of a symlink to the script itself, horrible though it is.

Answer (score 2):

`readlink -f` would be the best if it was portable, because it resolves every links found for both directories and files.

On mac os x there is no `readlink -f` (except maybe via macports), so you can only use `readlink` to get the destination of a specific symbolic link file.

The `$(cd -P ... pwd -P)` technique is nice but only works to resolve links for directories leading to the script, it doesn't work if the script itself is a symlink

Also, one case that wasn't mentioned : when you launch a script by passing it as an argument to a shell (`/bin/sh /path/to/myscript.sh`), `$0` is not usable in this case

I took a look to mysql "binaries", many of them are actually shell scripts ; and now i understand why they ask for a `--basedir` option or need to be launched from a specific working directory ; this is because there is no good solution to locate the targeted script

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did:

```
if [[ $0 != "/"* ]]; then
  DIR=`pwd`/`dirname $0`
else
  DIR=`dirname $0`
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

This works also, although it won't give the "true" path if it's a link. It's simpler, but less exact.

```
SCRIPT_PATH="$(whence ${0})"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try which command.

```
which scriptname
```

will give you the full qualified name of the script along with its absolute path

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded the Edward Staudt's answer, to be able to deal with absolute-path symbolic links, and with chains of links too.

```
DZERO=$0
while true; do
  echo "Trying to find real dir for script $DZERO"
  CPATH=$( cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "$(command -v -- "$DZERO")")" && pwd -P )
  CFILE=$CPATH/`basename $DZERO`
  if [ `ls -dl $CFILE | grep -c "^l" 2>/dev/null` -eq 0 ];then
    break
  fi
  LNKTO=`ls -ld $CFILE | cut -d ">" -f2 | tr -d " " 2>/dev/null`
  DZERO=`cd $CPATH ; command -v $LNKTO`
done
```

Ugly, but works...
After run this, the path is $CPATH and the file is $CFILE

Answer (score -1):

Try using this:

```
dir = $(dirname $0)
```

Answer (score -1):

Using $_ provides the last command.

```
>source my_script
```

Works if I issue the command twice:

```
>source my_script
>source my_script
```

If I use a different sequence of commands:

```
>who
>source my_script
```

The $_ variable returns "who"