# How to get script directory in POSIX sh?

Tags: bash, posix, sh

I have the following code in my bash script. Now I wanna use it in POSIX sh. How can I convert it?

```
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" > /dev/null && pwd )"
```

Comment: The problem there is not the array. The problem there is `BASH_SOURCE` which is a bash-ism. There are other answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in) and there's the http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028

Comment: Your problem isn't so much with arrays as with the `BASH_SOURCE` variable, which, obviously, is available only in `bash`.

Comment: @EtanReisner, thanks. I have updated my question. do you know what is the substitution of BASH_SOURCE in posix sh? thanks

Comment: Try `DIR=$( cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "$(command -v -- "$0")")" && pwd -P )`, what I found at `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/760110/can-i-get-the-absolute-path-to-the-current-script-in-kornshell`.

Comment: I wonder what that `command` usage is supposed to be doing there. That seems like a mistake for anything not in the `PATH`.

Comment: @EtanReisner: The `command -v` will work as long as its argument is a _path_ to an _executable file_ (as opposed to a mere _filename_, in which case matches would be limited to the `$PATH`). However, it merely echoes that path _as is_, and while it seems to do no harm, I have no idea why it's there.

Comment: @mklement0 Do you have a reference for that behavior of `command`? I see the spec saying "*command_names* including a <slash> character ... shall be written as absolute pathnames" but that doesn't say anything about the executable part.

Comment: @EtanReisner: I think it's implied by this passage from the [POSIX spec. of `command`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html) (emphasis mine): "When the `-v` or `-V` option is used, the command utility shall provide information concerning how a *command name* is interpreted by the shell."

Comment: @mklement0 I went looking for a concrete definition of *command_name* but couldn't find one (I didn't look for *command name*) but maybe that's it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash script: set current working directory to the directory of the script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349105/bash-script-set-current-working-directory-to-the-directory-of-the-script)

Comment: See also: [Reliable way for a bash script to get the full path to itself?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4774054/55075)

Comment: And: [Can a Bash script tell what directory it's stored in?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/59895/55075)

Comment: @kenorb: Note that this question is explicitly about the _POSIX shell_ (`sh`), not `bash`, which is what the question you link to are tagged with; even though the answers there happen to contain solutions that are also POSIX-compliant, they aren't discussed as such.

Comment: @EtanReisner: _command_name_ is defined as "The name of a utility or a special built-in utility" - I guess any executable file qualifies as a utility. The page also states, "_command_names_ including a <slash> character … shall be written as absolute pathnames" - note the _absolute_, which only `ksh` implements that way - `dash`, `bash`, and `zsh` simply echo the path _as specified_. As an additional curiosity, `dash` also echoes executable _directories_. I think I finally figured out the purpose of `command -v -- "$0"` - it's to - sort of - cover _sourced_ invocation; see my updated answer.

Comment: @EtanReisner: Addendum: `dash` actually echoes ANY existing path passed to `command -v` - even _directories_ - being executable is _not_ a requirement - unlike in `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh`.

Comment: ``CURRENT_SCRIPT_DIRECTORY="$(basename "`pwd "$(dirname -- readlink $0)"`")"``

Answer (score 177, accepted):

The POSIX-shell (`sh`) counterpart of `$BASH_SOURCE` is `$0`. <sup>see bottom for background info</sup>

**Caveat**: The crucial difference is that **if your script is being *sourced* (loaded into the *current* shell with `.`)**, the **snippets below will *not* work properly.** <sup>explanation further below</sup>

<sup>Note that I've changed `DIR` to `dir` in the snippets below, because it's [better not to use all-uppercase variable names](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_01) so as to avoid clashes with environment variables and special shell variables.

The `CDPATH=`  prefix takes the place of `> /dev/null` in the original command: `$CDPATH` is set to a null string so as to ensure that `cd` never *echoes* anything.</sup>

In the simplest case, this will do (the **equivalent of the OP's command**):

```
dir=$(CDPATH= cd -- "$(dirname -- "$0")" && pwd)
```

If you also want to **resolve the *resulting* directory path to its ultimate target in case the directory and/or its components are *symlinks***, add `-P` to the `pwd` command:

```
dir=$(CDPATH= cd -- "$(dirname -- "$0")" && pwd -P)
```

**Caveat**: This is **NOT** the same as finding **the script's own true directory of origin**:
Let's say your script `foo` is symlinked to `/usr/local/bin/foo` in the `$PATH`, but its true path is `/foodir/bin/foo`.
The above will still report `/usr/local/bin`, because the  symlink resolution (`-P`) is applied to the *directory*, `/usr/local/bin`, rather than to the script itself.

**To find the script's own true directory of origin**, you'd have to inspect the *script's* path to **see if it's a *symlink*** and, if so, follow the (chain of) symlinks to the ultimate target file, and then extract the directory path from the  *target* file's canonical path.

GNU's `readlink -f` (better: `readlink -e`) could do that for you, but `readlink` is not a POSIX utility.
<sup>While BSD platforms, including macOS, have a `readlink` utility too, on macOS it doesn't support `-f`'s functionality. That said, to show **how simple the task becomes *if* `readlink -f` is available**: 
`dir=$(dirname "$(readlink -f -- "$0")")`.</sup>

In fact, there is ***no* POSIX utility for resolving *file* symlinks**.
There are ways to work around that, but they're cumbersome and not fully robust:

The **following, *POSIX-compliant shell function* implements what GNU's `readlink -e` does** and is a **reasonably robust solution** that **only fails in two rare edge cases**:

- paths with embedded *newlines* (very rare)
- filenames containing literal string `->` (also rare)

With this function, named `rreadlink`, defined, **the following determines the script's true directory path of origin**:

```
dir=$(dirname -- "$(rreadlink "$0")")
```

**Note**: If you're willing to assume the presence of a (non-POSIX) `readlink` utility - which would cover macOS, FreeBSD and Linux - a similar, but simpler solution can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12145443/45375) to a related question.

`rreadlink()` **source code** - **place *before* calls to it** in scripts:

```sh
rreadlink() ( # Execute the function in a *subshell* to localize variables and the effect of `cd`.

  target=$1 fname= targetDir= CDPATH=

  # Try to make the execution environment as predictable as possible:
  # All commands below are invoked via `command`, so we must make sure that `command`
  # itself is not redefined as an alias or shell function.
  # (Note that command is too inconsistent across shells, so we don't use it.)
  # `command` is a *builtin* in bash, dash, ksh, zsh, and some platforms do not even have
  # an external utility version of it (e.g, Ubuntu).
  # `command` bypasses aliases and shell functions and also finds builtins 
  # in bash, dash, and ksh. In zsh, option POSIX_BUILTINS must be turned on for that
  # to happen.
  { \unalias command; \unset -f command; } >/dev/null 2>&1
  [ -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ] && options[POSIX_BUILTINS]=on # make zsh find *builtins* with `command` too.

  while :; do # Resolve potential symlinks until the ultimate target is found.
      [ -L "$target" ] || [ -e "$target" ] || { command printf '%s\n' "ERROR: '$target' does not exist." >&2; return 1; }
      command cd "$(command dirname -- "$target")" # Change to target dir; necessary for correct resolution of target path.
      fname=$(command basename -- "$target") # Extract filename.
      [ "$fname" = '/' ] && fname='' # !! curiously, `basename /` returns '/'
      if [ -L "$fname" ]; then
        # Extract [next] target path, which may be defined
        # *relative* to the symlink's own directory.
        # Note: We parse `ls -l` output to find the symlink target
        #       which is the only POSIX-compliant, albeit somewhat fragile, way.
        target=$(command ls -l "$fname")
        target=${target#* -> }
        continue # Resolve [next] symlink target.
      fi
      break # Ultimate target reached.
  done
  targetDir=$(command pwd -P) # Get canonical dir. path
  # Output the ultimate target's canonical path.
  # Note that we manually resolve paths ending in /. and /.. to make sure we have a normalized path.
  if [ "$fname" = '.' ]; then
    command printf '%s\n' "${targetDir%/}"
  elif  [ "$fname" = '..' ]; then
    # Caveat: something like /var/.. will resolve to /private (assuming /var@ -> /private/var), i.e. the '..' is applied
    # AFTER canonicalization.
    command printf '%s\n' "$(command dirname -- "${targetDir}")"
  else
    command printf '%s\n' "${targetDir%/}/$fname"
  fi
)
```

To be robust and predictable, the function uses `command` to ensure that only shell builtins or external utilities are called (ignores overloads in the forms of aliases and functions).
It's been **tested in recent versions of the following shells: `bash`, `dash`, `ksh`, `zsh`.**

---

#### How to handle *sourced* invocations:

**tl;dr**:

Using ***POSIX features** only*:

- You ***cannot* determine the script's path** in a ***sourced* invocation** (except in `zsh`, which, however, doesn't usually act as `sh`).
- You **can *detect whether or not* your script is being sourced ONLY if your script is being sourced *directly* by the shell** (such as in a shell profile/initialization file; possibly via a *chain* of sourcings), by comparing `$0` to the shell executable name/path (except in `zsh`, where, as noted `$0` is truly the current script's path). By contrast (except in `zsh`), a script being sourced from *another script* that itself was *directly invoked*, contains *that* script's path in `$0`.
- **To solve these problems, `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh` have *nonstandard* features** that *do* allow determining the actual script path even in sourced scenarios and also detecting whether a script is being sourced or not; for instance, in `bash`, `$BASH_SOURCE` *always* contains the running script's path, whether it's being sourced or not, and `[[ $0 != "$BASH_SOURCE" ]]` can be used to test whether the script is being sourced.

  - [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28776166/45375) indirectly shows these techniques, in the context of determining whether a given script is being sourced.

**To show why this cannot be done**, let's analyze the command from [Walter A's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29834779/45375):

```
    # NOT recommended - see discussion below.
    DIR=$( cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "$(command -v -- "$0")")" && pwd -P )
```

- (Two asides:

  - Using `-P` twice is redundant - it's sufficient to use it with `pwd`.
  - The command is missing silencing of `cd`'s potential stdout output, if `$CDPATH` happens to be set.)
- **`command -v -- "$0"`**

  - `command -v -- "$0"` is designed to cover one additional scenario: if the script is being *sourced* from an *interactive* shell, `$0` typically contains the *mere filename* of the shell executable (`sh`), in which case `dirname` would simply return `.` (because that's what `dirname` invariably does when given a argument without a *path* component).
    `command -v -- "$0"` then returns that shell's absolute path through a `$PATH` lookup (`/bin/sh`). Note, however, that *login* shells on some platforms (e.g., OSX) have their filename prefixed with `-` in `$0` (`-sh`), in which case `command -v -- "$0"` doesn't work as intended (returns an *empty string*).
  - Conversely, **`command -v -- "$0"` can misbehave in two *non*-sourced scenarios** in which the shell executable, `sh`, is *directly* invoked, with the script as an argument:

    - if the script itself is *not* executable: `command -v -- "$0"` may return an *empty string*, depending on what specific shell acts as `sh` on a given system: `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh` return an empty string; only `dash` echoes `$0`
      <sup>The [POSIX spec. for `command`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html) doesn't explicitly say whether `command -v`, when applied to a *filesystem path*, should only return *executable files* - which is what `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh` do - but you can argue that it is implied by the very purpose of `command`; curiously, `dash`, which is usually the most compliant POSIX citizen, is deviating from the standard here. By contrast, `ksh` is the lone model citizen here, because it is the only one that reports executable files only *and* reports them with an *absolute* (albeit not normalized) path, as the spec requires.</sup>
    - if the script *is* executable, but not in the `$PATH`, and the invocation uses its *mere filename* (e.g., `sh myScript`), `command -v -- "$0"` will also return the *empty string*, except in `dash`.
  - Given that the script's directory *cannot* be determined when the script is being *sourced* - because `$0` then doesn't contain that information (except in `zsh`, which doesn't usually act as `sh`) - there's no good solution to this problem.

    - Returning the *shell executable's* directory path in that situation is of limited use - it is, after all, not the *script's* directory - except perhaps to later use that path in a *test* to determine *whether or not* the script is being sourced.

      - A more reliable approach would be to simply test `$0` directly: `[ "$0" = "sh" ] || [ "$0" = "-sh" ] || [ "$0" = "/bin/sh" ]`
    - However, even that doesn't work if the script is being sourced from *another* script (that was itself *directly* invoked), because `$0` then simply contains the *sourcing* script's path.
  - Given the limited usefulness of `command -v -- "$0"` in sourced scenarios and the fact that it breaks two *non*-sourced scenarios, **my vote is for NOT using it**,  which leaves us with:

    - **All *non*-sourced scenarios *are* covered.**
    - **In *sourced* invocations, you *cannot determine the script's path*, and at best, in limited circumstances, you can *detect whether or not* sourcing is occurring:**

      - When sourced *directly* by the shell (such as from a shell profile/initialization file), `$dir` ends up either containing `.`, if the shell executable was invoked as a mere filename (applying `dirname` to a mere filename *always* returns `.`), or the shell executable's directory path otherwise. `.` cannot be reliably distinguished from a non-sourced invocation from the current directory.
      - When sourced from *another script* (that was itself not also sourced), `$0` contains *that* script's path, and the script being sourced has no way of telling whether that's the case.

---

#### Background information:

**POSIX** defines the **behavior of `$0` with respect to shell *scripts*** [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html#).

Essentially, `$0` should reflect the path of the script file *as specified*, which implies:

- **Do NOT rely on `$0` containing an *absolute* path**.
- `$0` contains an ***absolute* path** only if:
- you *explicitly* specify an *absolute* path; e.g.:

  - `~/bin/myScript` (assuming the script itself is executable)
  - `sh ~/bin/myScript`
- you invoke an executable script by *mere filename*, which requires that it both be executable *and* in the `$PATH`; behind the scenes, the system transforms `myScript` into an absolute path and then executes it; e.g.:

  - `myScript   # executes /home/jdoe/bin/myScript, for instance`
- In all other cases, `$0` will reflect the script **path *as specified***:

  - When explicitly invoking `sh` with a script, this can be a *mere filename* (e.g., `sh myScript`) or a *relative path* (e.g., `sh ./myScript`)
  - When invoking an executable script *directly*, this can be a *relative* path (e.g., `./myScript` - note that a *mere filename* would only find scripts *in the `$PATH`*).

In practice, **`bash`, `dash`, `ksh`, and `zsh` all exhibit this behavior.**

By contrast, **POSIX does NOT mandate the value of `$0` when *sourcing* a script** (using the special built-in utility `.` ("dot")), so **you cannot rely on it**, and, in practice, **behavior differs across shells.**

- Thus, you cannot blindly use `$0` when your script is being sourced and expect standardized behavior.

  - In practice, `bash`, `dash`, and `ksh` leave `$0` *untouched* when sourcing scripts, meaning that `$0` contains the *caller's* `$0` value, or, more accurately, the `$0` value of the most recent caller in the call chain that hasn't been sourced itself; thus, `$0` may point either to the shell's executable or to the path of *another* (directly invoked) script that sourced the current one.
  - By contrast, `zsh`, as the lone dissenter, actually *does* report the *current* script's path in `$0`. Conversely, `$0` will provide no indication as to whether the script is being sourced or not.
  - **In short: using POSIX features only, you can neither tell reliably whether the script at hand is being sourced, nor what the script at hand's path is, nor what the relationship of `$0` to the current script's path is.**
- If you do need to handle this situation, **you must identify the specific shell at hand and access its *specific* non-standard features**:

  - `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh` all offer their *own* ways of obtaining the running script's path, even when it's being sourced.

For the sake of completeness: the **value of `$0` in *other* contexts**:

- **Inside a shell *function***, POSIX mandates that `$0` remain *unchanged*; therefore, whatever value it has *outside* the function, it'll have *inside* as well.

  - In practice, `bash`, `dash`, and `ksh` do behave that way.
  - Again, `zsh` is the lone dissenter and reports the *function's* name.
- In a shell that accepted a **command string via the `-c` option** on startup, it's the *first operand* (non-option argument) that sets `$0`; e.g.:

  - `sh -c 'echo \$0: $0 \$1: $1' foo one  # -> '$0: foo $1: one'`
  - `bash`, `dash`, `ksh`, and `zsh` all behave that way.
- **Otherwise**, in a shell *not* executing a *script file*, **`$0` is the value of the first argument that the shell's *parent process* passed** - typically, that's the *shell's* name or path (e.g. `sh`, or `/bin/sh`); this includes:

  - an ***interactive* shell**

    - **Caveat**: some platforms, notably OSX, always create *login* shells when creating interactive shells, and *prepend `-`* to the shell name before placing it in `$0`, so as to signal to the shell that it is a _login shell; thus, by default, `$0` reports `-bash`, not `bash`, in interactive shells on OSX.
  - a shell that reads **commands from *stdin***

    - this also applies to piping a script file to the shell via stdin (e.g., `sh < myScript`)
  - `bash`, `dash`, `ksh`, and `zsh` all behave that way.

Comment: @Sandburg: I've added a link to the answer you mentioned to this answer, with a caveat that it relies on the non-POSIX `readlink` utility; given that macOS, FreeBSD and Linux all have this utility, it is a pragmatic and simpler alternative that may work for many.

Comment: thanks for the rreadlink() function, very helpful! This line: 

`command cd "$(command dirname -- "$target")"` 

located inside the `while` loop, emits some unexpected output on macOS. I fixed it for my situation by redirecting output to /dev/null: 

`command cd "$(command dirname -- "$target")" >/dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: Incredible script for rreadlink(), I am linking to this answer in the script I'm using this in. You have done a fantastic service for the worldwide POSIX community.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it, @cosmicexplorer; I appreciate the nice feedback.

Comment: @xmnboy, looks like I never responded to your comment: thanks for the hint, but I don't see this problem (as of macOS 11.5.1, where `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)` acts as `/bin/sh`) - what unexpected output, specifically, are you getting?

Comment: @mklement0 -- sorry for the delayed response. I just tried to reproduce the issue I encountered on bash 3.x and 5.x (on macOS), as well as on relatively current releases of the dash, ksh and zsh shells, but was not successful. As an aside, I do recall running into a different issue with `ksh` but that turned out to be a problem with the `ksh` implementation, not your script. Regardless, thank you for this script, it has been _extremely valuable_ for building POSIX-compliant shell scripts that must be sourced and need to know their absolute location.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it, @xmnboy - thanks for the nice feedback.

Answer (score 4):

@City responded that

```
DIR=$( cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "$(command -v -- "$0")")" && pwd -P )
```

works. I used it too.
I found the command at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760110/can-i-get-the-absolute-path-to-the-cu‌​rrent-script-in-kornshell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760110/can-i-get-the-absolute-path-to-the-cu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Brrent-script-in-kornshell).

Comment: No harm, but generally other stack posts are referenced in comments, not posted as answers. The SO format for providing the link is [Link Title](url). (you can include normal bold by surrounding the Link Title with double-asterisks) E.g. [**Can I get the absolute path to the current script in KornShell?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/760110/can-i-get-the-absolute-path-to-the-current-script-in-kornshell)

Comment: @David Thanks for format, I did post it as a comment first. I had a response that my comment worked, so I wanted to offer a possibility to close the question. Other people might think City is still looking for an answer now. Can you advise how I should have done it?

Comment: Even if the comment worked, it should be left as a reference in the comment. Why? Because the answer is already on SO, and one huge headache on SO is having negligibly differing versions of the same answer scattered all over SO under different questions. The goal being to have all related answers under a single question so they are easily found/referenced for all. (We will never get there 100%, but when you find the answer under another question, please do not duplicate it yet again)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Note that this question is explicitly about the _POSIX shell_ (`sh`), whereas the question linked here is about `ksh`, and the questions linked in comments at the top are `bash` questions; while _some_ of the answers to those questions happen to contain solutions that are also POSIX-compliant, they aren't discussed as such, and even though this question is closely related, it is distinct, of general interest, and deserves its own, canonical answer here.
Perhaps Walter could have copied the ksh-tagged solution _and explained_ why it works with _all_ POSIX-compliant shells.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
if [ -f "$0" ]; then script=$0; else script=$(command -v -- "$0"); fi
dir=$(dirname -- "$script")
dir=$(CDPATH=; cd -- "$dir" && pwd -P)
```

When a relative directory is all I need, as is usual, I omit the last line.

## Conditions

The snippet gives the right answer if the script is directly invoked (e.g., `script` or `path/to/script`), or if the shell is directly invoked with the script as first argument (`sh script` or `sh path/to/script`). You can use any POSIX-compliant shell instead of `sh`.

The snippet does *not* give the right answer if the script is sourced (`. script` or `. path/to/script`). Some shells, such as bash and ksh93, have nonportable features that will let you get the answer, but it can't be done within POSIX.

The third line resolves directory symlinks; if you don't want to do that, remove the `-P` after `pwd`. The snippet does not resolve file symlinks. POSIX provides no simple way to do so.

The snippet must appear before the script `cd`s for the first time.

## How it works

The snippet's first line

```sh
if [ -f "$0" ]; then script=$0; else script=$(command -v -- "$0"); fi
```

computes a path to the script. In most cases that satisfy the conditions above, `$0` is that path. `[ -f "$0" ]` yields true, and `$0` is assigned to the variable `script`.

Now suppose your script is invoked via `sh script`. That is, the shell is directly invoked and the script filename, without a slash character, is the first argument. There are two cases: either the script exists in the current working directory (first case) or it doesn't, but it's on the PATH (second case).

In the first case, `$0` is the script filename, which is also a correct path. It's assigned to the variable `script`, as above.

In the second case, POSIX allows the [shell](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html) to search the PATH. (Some shells do, like bash and ksh93. Others don't, like dash and mksh. We assume we're in a shell that does.) `$0` is again the script filename. But this time it isn't a path to the script, because the script doesn't exist in the cwd! `[ -f "$0" ]` yields false; `command -v` finds the script on the PATH; and the result is assigned to the variable `script`.

The first case is why the first line cannot be reduced to `script=$(command -v -- "$0")`; that would fail or produce the wrong result if the cwd were not in the PATH. The second case is why the first line cannot be reduced to `script=$0`.

Let's move on to the second line:

```sh
dir=$(dirname -- "$script")
```

It extracts the directory part of `$script`. Nothing to talk about there.

Finally, the third line

```sh
dir=$(CDPATH=; cd -- "$dir" && pwd -P)
```

ensures that the directory is absolute, and resolves directory symlinks.

The third line sets CDPATH to empty because otherwise, `cd` can misbehave. And it does so in a separate statement (`CDPATH=; cd`) rather than in the same statement (`CDPATH= cd`) because the latter doesn't have the desired effect in `/bin/sh` and `/bin/ksh` on AIX, IBM's Unix.

Answer (score 0):

```
if      OLDPWD=/dev/fd/0 \
        cd - && ls -lLidFH ?
then    cd . <8
fi      </proc/self/fd 8<. 9<$0
```

there. that should enable you to change directpry through some magic links as file descriptors.

setting `$OLDPWD` pre-`cd` exports the value for the duration of the one change directory *(note: `cd` can have residual effects on `hash` tables, but the only `sh` about which i am aware that actually males any good use of these is kevin ahlmquists - and since herbert xu - `dash`, and maybe some `bsd` stuff, but what do i know?)* but does not carry over any `cd` exports as a result of the change.

thus, `$OLDPWD` does not change, actually, and if it had any value at all this remains as was. `$PWD` is changed as a result of the first `cd`, and the value becomes `/dev/fd/0` which points to `/proc/self/fd`, where a list of file descriptors for our process should be in `.`, to include whatever `$0` is on `./2`.

so we do an `ls ... ?` and have a look at all of the wonderful info we can get, and we go whence we came.

yay!

Comment: The question is about a POSIX-compliant solution, so you cannot rely on Linux filesystem (`/proc/self`). Unless you run the script sourced - in which you can't rely on `$0` anyway - you needn't worry about `OLDPWD` (which isn't a POSIX-mandated shell variable to begin with). When I run this on Ubuntu 18.04, I get literal `/dev/fd/0`, followed by a listing of the process' file descriptors (plus an error message about descriptor `3`) - I don't see the script's (symlink-resolved) _directory path_, which is what the question is about.

Comment: @mklement0:  yo. <script> resolves symlinks with either of `cd -[LP]` for link memories sh local or properly canonical. the former method enables a `ln -sf  ~/../~\${../tmp/;cd <./0/.. -L [.-\9]` or `similar; for CDPATH in

Comment: @mklement0:  yo. <script> resolves symlinks with either of `cd -[LP]` for link memories sh local or properly canonical. the former method enables a `ln -sf  <~nobody/onthisfreakyphonedoesntchargeagainanduponwhichicannottestthisstuffforthreeyearswhilemysoniskidnappedbyunitedstatesnavy ~/../~"${HOME##*/}" /dev/fd/0;2<>~/../\~` ...  ehh... bored. cant even charge this last vestige of computing available... `OLDPWD=/proc/$$/fd/$?/../root<~ cd -L ->>; cd -L ../$?<~somename` and so on.. theres another name space. try putting executables in an fd and linkinkg over them... you can mount like that.

Comment: This is amazing madness, but it does show the principle, and works, with modification, to output just the symlink target of the file descriptor to itself. I have ksh, dash, bash working easily, zsh not immediately. If we're using Linux anyway, `find /proc/$$/fd -lname "*${0##*/}" -printf '%l\n'` gives the script itself, then dirname it.