# Get current directory and concatenate a path

Tags: shell

This is a shell script (.sh file). I need to create an absolute path based on the current directory. I know about `pwd`, but how do I concatenate it with another string? Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
"$pwd/some/path"
```

Comment: What's your shell? Some shells maintain a `$PWD` variable so you don't have to call out to `pwd`

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Sounds like you want:

```
path="$(pwd)/some/path"
```

The `$(` opens a subshell (and the `)` closes it) where the contents are executed as a script so any outputs are put in that location in the string.

---

More useful often is getting the directory of the script that is running:

```
dot="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")"; pwd)"
path="$dot/some/path"
```

That's more useful because it resolves to the same path no matter where you are when you run the script:

```
> pwd
~
> ./my_project/my_script.sh
~/my_project/some/path
```

rather than:

```
> pwd
~
> ./my_project/my_script.sh
~/some/path
> cd my_project
> pwd
~/my_project
> ./my_script.sh
~/my_project/some/path
```

---

More complex but if you need the directory of the current script running if it has been executed through a symlink (common when installing scripts through homebrew for example) then you need to parse and follow the symlink:

```
if [[ "$OSTYPE" == *darwin* ]]; then
  READLINK_CMD='greadlink'
else
  READLINK_CMD='readlink'
fi

dot="$(cd "$(dirname "$([ -L "$0" ] && $READLINK_CMD -f "$0" || echo "$0")")"; pwd)"
```

More complex and more requirements for it to work (e.g. having a gnu compatible readlink installed) so I tend not to use it as much. Only when I'm certain I need it, like installing a command through homebrew.

Comment: While `$(pwd)` works, it's simpler (and marginally more efficient) to use `$PWD`, which is a POSIX-mandated shell variable. Good tip re determining the _running script's_ directory, but note that this may not work as expected if the script was invoked through a _symlink_. Unfortunately, there is no straightforward solution that's also portable.

Comment: True true, symlinks can make it more complex, I'll update it to show that.

Comment: Thanks for updating. Because `readlink -f` reports the absolute target path even when the argument is _not_ a symlink, you could simplify to `dot=$(dirname -- "$(READLINK_CMD -f -- "$0")")`. Note that using `$OSTYPE` is not portable (`bash` and `zsh` have it, though). I've created a POSIX-compliant shell function [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29835459/45375).

Answer (score 7):

Using the shell builtin `pwd` in a command substitution (`$(...)`) is an option, but not necessary, because **all POSIX-compatible shells define the special `$PWD` shell variable that contains the current directory as an absolute path**, as [mandated by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_03).

Thus, **using `$PWD` is both simpler and more efficient than `$(pwd)`**:

```
"$PWD/some/path"  # alternatively, for visual clarity: "${PWD}/some/path"
```

However, **if you wanted to resolve symlinks** in the directory path, **you DO need `pwd`**, with its **`-P` option**:

```
"$(pwd -P)/some/path"
```

<sup>Note that [POSIX mandates that `$PWD` contain an absolute pathname *with symlinks resolved*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02).
In practice, however, NO major POSIX-like shell (`bash`, `dash`, `ksh`, `zsh`) does that - they all retain symbolic link components. Thus, the (POSIX-compliant) [`pwd -P`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pwd.html) is needed to resolve them.

Note that all said POSIX-like shells implement `pwd` as a *builtin* that supports `-P`.</sup>

---

[Michael Allen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30187926/45375) points out that **it's common to want to know the directory of where the *running script* is located**.

The **challenge is that the script file *itself* may be a symlink**, so **determining the true directory of origin is *non-trivial***, especially when portability is a must.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29835459/45375) (of mine) shows a solution.

Comment: `$(env pwd)` is a portable alternative to `$(pwd -P)`

Comment: @DavidJones: `pwd -P` _is_ portable [(POSIX-compliant](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pwd.html)). The major POSIX-like shells implement it as a builtin (`bash`, `dash`, `ksh`, `zsh`). By contrast, `env pwd` executes the external-utility form of `pwd`, typically `/bin/pwd`. These implementations differ across platforms with respect to their default behavior: GNU `/bin/pwd` defaults to `-P`, but BSD/macOS `/bin/pwd` does not, so for portability you'd have to use `-P` as well, but there's no advantage to calling the external-utility form of `pwd` - it'll just be slower

Answer (score 1):

```
wd=`pwd`
new_path="$wd/some/path"
```

Answer (score 0):

with  "`dirname $0`" you can get dynamin path upto current run scipt.
for example : your file is locateted in shell folder file name is xyz and there are anthor file abc to include in xyz file.
so put in xyz file LIke:

```
       php   "`dirname $0`"/abc.php
```