# how to use one validation function many times "bash centos"

Tags: bash, function, shell

I want to use only one validation function many times. I tried to make a validation function like beneath. How can I fix my code and use the validation function like this one many times?

```
#!/bin/bash
digit='^[[:digit:]]+$';
function numberValidate {
    if [[ $1 =~ $digit ]];
       then
          echo "$1 is number. Correct";
       else
          echo “Enter only numbers”;
          numberValidate
    fi
}
printf “Enter the number 1 ”; read n1;
numberValidate $n1
printf “Enter the  number 2”; read n2;
numberValidate $n2
```

Thanks.

Comment: The recursive call to `numberValidate` when there's a problem is probably wrong.  The function doesn't get passed any value but it expects one, and it doesn't prompt for a value.  You need to think a bit harder about how to get this to work.  You'll need to be able to prompt (again) for a number from within the function, and you'll need to be able to get the value out of the function somehow...

Comment: The use of smart quotes here is one thing that's obviously wrong. Was your code copied and pasted from a Microsoft platform?

Comment: That said, there's no actual **question** in this question -- it's nothing but a dump of code that shows that you already *do* know how to call a function more than once (which is what the title would seem to indicate you to be asking). If you're asking why the code fails in a given way, describe the failure mode and what you intend it to do; see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use recursion when a loop will do:

```
inputNumber () {
    local digit='^[[:digit:]]+$'
    read $n
    until [[ ${!n} =~ $digit ]]; do
        echo "Enter only numbers"
        read $n
    done
}
printf "Enter the number 1 "; inputNumber n1
printf "Enter the number 2 "; inputNumber n2
```

The preceding moves all the input into the validation function, and takes advantage of the fact that variables set in a function are global by default. The argument to `inputNumber` is the *name* of the variable to set.

Comment: In this case no difference, but I would suggest `printf "%s" "Enter the number 1 "`.

Comment: I tried your code and it didn't work for me. I had to make the following changes:  No indirection on n (`read n` and `${n} =~ $digit`) and add the line `printf -v $1 '%s' $n`. What did I miss in your solution?

Comment: Good question; I'm not sure.

Comment: I needed to add oneline, just before `read $n`. The line was `n="$1"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
inputNumber () {
    local digit='^[[:digit:]]+$'
    outputvar=$1
    shift
    if [[ $# = 0 ]]; then
       read -p "Please enter a number for ${outputvar} "
    else
       read -p "$* " n
    fi
    until [[ "${n}" =~ $digit ]]; do
        read -p "Enter only numbers " n
    done
    printf -v "${outputvar}" '%s' "$n"
}

inputNumber n1 "Enter the number 1"
inputNumber n2 "Enter the number 2"
inputNumber n3
echo "n1=${n1} n2=${n2} n3=${n3}"
```

Question in a comment: How to reuse these?
When you like functions like this one, you can collect them in files and put them in a dedicated directory. Perhaps choose ${HOME}/shlib as a folder and create files like iofunctions, datefunctions, dbfunctions and webfunctions (or io.sh, date.sh, db.sh and  web.sh).
Next you can `source` the files with a dot:

```
$ head -2 ${HOME}/shlib/iofunctions
# This file should be included with ". path/iofunctions"
function inputnumber {

$ cat ${HOME}/bin/roger.sh
#!/bin/bash
# Some settings
shlibpath=/home/roger/shlib
# Include utilities
. "${shlibpath}"/iofunctions
# Let's rock
inputNumber rockcount How many rocks
# call an imaginary function that only accepts y and n
inputyn letsdoit Are you sure
```

You can put the functions (or source the function files) in your .profile/.bashrc, but that will give problems when you want to start the script in crontab (and you will get used to the functions and forget that inputNumber is not a standard bash function).
Another question is how you can refer to another directory that is on the same level as your script file (not a fixed path). Including `../shlib/iofunctions` will fail when you start your script using a path (like `bin/roger.sh`). A good question with many answers, I can't tell which is the best:
[How to set current working directory to the directory of the script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3349105/3220113)
[Getting the source directory of a Bash script from within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in)
[Reliable way for a bash script to get the full path to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774054/reliable-way-for-a-bash-script-to-get-the-full-path-to-itself)
[How to set current working directory to the directory of the script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349105/how-to-set-current-working-directory-to-the-directory-of-the-script)
[how to get script directory in POSIX sh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29832037/how-to-get-script-directory-in-posix-sh)

Comment: To improve this code. this solution works in one file(bash). If y one to work in another file, I have to copy this function. "this function for each file(bash)".

Comment: THE QUESTION IS How I have in one file many functions and from another file only call this file to work.