# How to get the path of a sourced Bourne shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, sh

In Bash, the correct way to get the full path to a shell script is `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}`, since `$0` returns `bash` if the script is being sourced. For example, try running this in your terminal:

```
source <(echo 'echo $0')
```

It will print `bash`.

Does anyone know how to do this for Bourne shell scripts? For example, what would be the contents of a script `foo` such that if I typed this:

```
sh -c '. foo'
```

it would output the full path to the script?

Comment: Well, I put `foo` in my path and if it contains `echo ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` I get it's path echoed.

Comment: @nsilent22 Yes, that's true. But how would you do it for scripts written in **sh**? `BASH_SOURCE` is specific to Bash.

Comment: Crossposting: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/264438/74329

Comment: Oh... sorry. I didn't read carefully enough.

Comment: To note, '/bin/sh' does not necessarily mean the "Bourne shell". In fact it's almost guaranteed not to be, as Bourne is pretty ancient. On modern system, '/bin/sh' is usually a link to bash, dash, csh, ksh, etc.

I would try doing `ls -l /bin/sh` or `/bin/sh -v` or `/bin/sh --version` to see what shell you're really dealing with.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no POSIX-compliant way to do what you want; see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29835459/45375) of mine for the gory details.