# create quiet mode by supress stdout bash script

Tags: bash

I worte a bash script that have a few options turned on by switches from command line. 
I want to create option for the user to run this script in quiet mode which mean - all stdout will be redirected to /dev/null. 
i use a variable that is changed to /dev/null if the -q switch is on:

```
while getopts ":qhb:kape" opt; do
    case $opt in
       q)
        output=/dev/null
        ;;
```

and later i redirect acho mesagges to output:

```
echo "something" 1>>$output
```

My question is how to initilaize this var output above for case of no -q switch were sent. what is the value of standrd stdout destination (the text terminal that called the sctipt usually)?

thanks!

Comment: `case $opt in
       q)
        exec 1>/dev/null
        ;;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use two methods...

**Method 1**

At the very beginning in your script set `output` variable to its default value. For example:

```
output=/dev/stdout
```

then, if `-q` switch has been used "overwrite" this default value by setting `output=/dev/null`.

This method implies that each instruction in your script will have its output redirected to ${output}.

**Method 2**

Use exec... At the very beginning in your script:

```
exec 6>&1 # saves stdout
```

Then, if `-q` option has been selected:

```
exec > /dev/null  # redirect stdout to /dev/null
```

And, finally...

```
exec 1>&6 6>&- # restore stdout
```

This way you don't have to explicitly redirect each command output...

Answer (score 0):

Stdout file descriptor is `&1`

ie:

```
echo hello 1>&1
```

---

EDIT:

```
s=1
echo hello >& $s
```

Comment: i am trying to insert it into output variable, but the result is that nothing shown in the next command.
i want that by default, if i don;t change this var when the user use -q, it will appear in the terminal


echo "something" 1>>$output

Comment: While this works with your example, it won't work with a _single_ variable for _both_ cases, as is the OP's intent (using variable `$output` to represent either stdout or `/dev/null`, depending on option `-q`); in order to use `>&`, you'd need a file _descriptor_ in _both_ cases, and there is no file descriptor for `/dev/null`.
You could use _filenames_, however, as demonstrated in @mauro's answer.

Comment: Yup, you're right, you could open another fd like `exec 5>/dev/null`, but that's almost matching @mauro's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect stdout as below.

```
while getopts ":qhb:kape" opt; do
    case $opt in
    q)
        old_stdout=`readlink -f /dev/stdout` # save old stdout value if required.
        exec 1>/dev/null # redirect stdout to /dev/null
        ;
    ....
    esac
done

echo hello world # It will not be printed on the screen
echo hello universe > $old_stdout # will be printed to original stdout (say terminal)

exec 1>$old_stdout #revert stdout to original value (say terminal)
```

Comment: Good tip re `exec`, but `readlink -f` isn't portable; is there a reason not to use `/dev/stdout` directly? The most portable solution is to save the original stdout in a custom file descriptor, as in @mauro's answer.

Comment: We cannot use `/dev/stdout`, because that will also point to `/dev/null`... `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Mar  1 15:36 /dev/stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1`

Comment: But yes, using a separate file descriptor is a much better way.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation; I see that Linux behaves that way; on OSX, `/dev/stdout` actually keeps pointing to `/dev/fd/1`, even while redirected.

Comment: Where does `/dev/fd/1` point to? Is there any `readlink -f` like utility there? Anyone from [this](http://unix.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.unix.shell/2011-12/msg00113.html) link working? On linux, `/dev/fd/1` points to terminal by default & to `/dev/null` when redirected...

Comment: `/dev/fd/1` is not a symlink on OSX - it is the actual character special file. `readlink` exists, but not with `-f`, so you don't get an absolute path, and you don't get recursive resolution; GNU readlink can be installed via HomeBrew. A POSIX-compliant implementation of `readlink -f` can be found in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29835459/45375) of mine.