# Get path of currently executing shell script run with busybox

Tags: shell, sh, posix, busybox

In ConTeXt standalone, the file `tex/setuptex` contains code that needs the current path of `tex/setuptex` (which is usually e.g. `$HOME/context`, `/opt/context`, etc.).  The code looks like this:

```
# this resolves to path of the setuptex script
# We use $0 for determine the path to the script, except for:
# * bash where $0 always is bash; here we use BASH_SOURCE
# * ksh93 where we use ${.sh.file}
# Thanks to Vasile Gaburici and Alessandro Perucchi for reporting this
# * http://www.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2008/033953.html
# * http://www.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2012/068658.html
if [ z"$BASH_SOURCE" != z ]; then
        SCRIPTPATH="$BASH_SOURCE"
elif [ z"$KSH_VERSION" != z ]; then
        SCRIPTPATH="${.sh.file}"
else
        SCRIPTPATH="$0"
fi
```

One usually runs this to update the current environment with an assortment of environment variables needed to run ConTeXt, with `. path/tex/setuptex`.

In BusyBox (on e.g. Alpine Linux), the `$SCRIPTPATH` is `/`, and it's not apparent what the correct way to get the path would be.  Adding this line to the script:

```
echo "SCRIPTPATH $0 : $1 : $2"
```

yields:

> SCRIPTPATH sh :  :

Similarly `env` yields nothing with `setuptex`.

So I'm not certain where to start.

How does one replicate the `*sh` functionality one ordinarily uses to obtain the path of the currently executing script?

Comment: The problem is that you're sourcing the file (`. /path/to/context`) rather than running it (`sh /path/to/context`).  I don't have a solution for you, but you could consider workaround a workaround like: `. /path/to/context /path/to/context` will store the answer (potentially relative to `$PWD`) in `$1`

Comment: Thanks @AdamKatz; sourcing with `.` is in the instructions from ConTeXt, which a lot of people would be familiar with.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed you need `.` or `source` due to importing some combination of environment, functions, and/or aliases, which you can't pull in via new shells.  That's why all I can offer is that awkward workaround.  This may be a busybox bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Henri Menke (by email) -

> Standard POSIX sh has no way to reliably detect sourced invocation of a script.
>   BusyBox uses POSIX sh underneath and thus suffers from the same limitation. See
>   StackOverflow for detail: [how to get script directory in POSIX sh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29832037)