# How to get script directory (not current directory) in shell (sh) script (not bash)?

Tags: docker, shell, docker-compose

#### Folder structure:

```
#root
|- deployment
|  |- start-dev.sh
|  |- docker-compose.yml
|  |- // other files including app.Dockerfile and anything else I need
|- // everything else
```

#### Initial `start-dev.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/sh

docker-compose -p my-container up -d
docker-compose -p my-container exec app bash
```

#### Working state

In VS Code (opened as WSL2 remote) integrated terminal I would type

```
cd deployment
./start-dev.sh
```

and deployment is successful.

If instead, I tried just `deployment/start-dev.sh` it fails, since there's no docker-compose.yml in the current directory.

#### Desire

I want

```bash
deployment/start-dev.sh
```

to work.

#### Non-solution

The following fails since `dirname` is not available in my case.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

BASEDIR=$(dirname $0)

docker-compose -f "${BASEDIR}/docker-compose.yml" -p my-container up -d
docker-compose -f "${BASEDIR}/docker-compose.yml" -p my-container exec app bash
```

#### Solution 1 for `start-dev.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

BASEDIR=$(dirname $0)

docker-compose -f "${BASEDIR}/docker-compose.yml" -p my-container up -d
docker-compose -f "${BASEDIR}/docker-compose.yml" -p my-container exec app bash
```

#### Question

How do I convert Solution 1 to be a `sh` script instead of `bash`, if `dirname` is not available in `sh`?

Comment: Since you are asking for a solution for _sh_, and post the bash example only for illustration, I suggest that you remove the _bash_ tag from your question.

Comment: What is the expected outcome, if your script has been invoked via a symlink? Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29832037/how-to-get-script-directory-in-posix-sh/29835459#29835459), which discusses the problem for various shells (also for sh) and presents a solution for symlinks too. In this link, it also explains under what condition $0 does **not** contain the path to the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution 2

```bash
#!/bin/sh

a="/$0"; a=${a%/*}; a=${a#/}; a=${a:-.}; BASEDIR=$(cd "$a"; pwd)

docker-compose -f "${BASEDIR}/docker-compose.yml" -p my-container up -d
docker-compose -f "${BASEDIR}/docker-compose.yml" -p my-container exec app bash
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the very first line of the script to use `#!/bin/sh` as the interpreter.  You don't need to change anything else.

In particular, the POSIX.1 specification includes [`dirname`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dirname.html#tag_20_35) and [`$(command)` substitution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03), so you're not using anything that's not a POSIX shell feature.  I'd expect this script to work in minimal but standard-conforming shells like [BusyBox](https://busybox.net)'s, and so in turn to work in any Docker image that includes a shell.

There are other recipes too, though they do typically rely on **dirname**(1).  See for example [How can I set the current working directory to the directory of the script in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349105/how-can-i-set-the-current-working-directory-to-the-directory-of-the-script-in-ba/17744637#17744637), which includes non-bash-specific answers.

Comment: I tried just that, but `dirname` was not supported, so I found the other solution. Thank you though

Comment: It's not a shell built-in (on my MacOS host there is a `/usr/bin/dirname` binary) so changing shells to a standards-conforming shell shouldn't make a difference here.

Comment: That's nice, but in my case there is not `/usr/bin/dirname` (Windows with WSL2, Docker, Ubuntu), so I needed a different solution, while not changing to `#!/bin/bash`.  Also I already posted a solution with `dirname` in the question myself. Thanks anyway.